# How to scrape table from website and export to excel using c#

Tags: c#, excel, web-scraping

I have a link and i want to apply webscraping through which i can get the  info of table and and then export this table into excel.Please suggest

```
  HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
        var myTable = doc.DocumentNode
                         .Descendants("table")
                         .Where(t => t.Attributes["id"].Value == someTableId)
                         .FirstOrDefault();

        if (myTable != null)
        {
            ///further parsing here
        }
```

the code i m gonna use is above mentioned.As I am beginner so anyone ca tell me what to do

Answer (score 1):

You may just continue iterating through table rows and cells:

```
 if (myTable != null)
    {
        int iRow=0;
        var tableRows = myTable
                     .Descendants("tr");

        foreach (var tableRow in tableRows)
        {
             var rowCells = tableRow
                     .Descendants("td");

             int iColumn=0;
             foreach (var cell in rowCells)
             {
                //Save to Excel code
                //Perform any checks here to ensure youre getting a valid value from the cell contents
                //Excel.Cell[iRow,iColumn++]=cell.InnerText;

             }
             iRow++;
        }
    }
}
```

You may use any third party tool to save the values to Excel, like [NPOI](https://npoi.codeplex.com/) for binary format (up to Excel 2003) or [ClosedXML](https://closedxml.codeplex.com/) if you want to use OpenXML format (Excel 2007 and above).

Comment: Thanks.Mack let me try it